# Jenkins in Docker: Unable to resolve VCS host

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm in the process of migrating my existing Jenkins instance from one server to Docker hosted in another server. I'm new to Docker, by the way.

I was able to run the Jenkins instance in Docker without problem. However, when I run a job, it wasn't able to connect to the VCS repo:-

```
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://tfs/path/to/app/': Could not resolve host: tfs
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:807)
```

How should my Docker configuration look in order to get the VCS host to resolve?

My current docker-compose.xml looks like this:-

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: "jenkinsci/jenkins"
    ports:
     - "80:8080"
    volumes:
     - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m"
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a internal DNS server(es), add them like this:

`dns: 1.2.3.4`

or

`dns:
   - 1.2.3.4
   - 4.3.2.1`

More info at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#dns

Or you can use `extra_hosts` like this:

`extra_hosts:
   - "tfs:x.x.x.x"`

Replace `x.x.x.x` with the IP of the `tfs` host.

More info at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extra_hosts

Comment: Thank you. Combination of `dns` and `dns_search` does the trick for me.